# External/non-WP rewrite rule without QSA

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I'm trying to add a new external/non-WP rewrite rule to my `.htaccess` but WP keeps adding `[QSA,L]` to the end of the rule.
How do I prevent the QSA part?

This line adds the RewriteRule:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_external_rule('go/([0-9]+)/?.*$', 'wp-content/plugins/xswpc/redirect.php?id=$1');
```

And this is the resulting line in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^go/([0-9]+)/?.*$ /wp-content/plugins/xswpc/redirect.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I'd like is:

```
RewriteRule ^go/([0-9]+)/?.*$ /wp-content/plugins/xswpc/redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apache rewrite flags like [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) are hard coded, see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L1802). Not sure why it would bother you, but if you really want to change it, then you can and should use the [`mod_rewrite_rules`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L1844) hook for that. Below an example on how to do it:

```
add_filter( 'mod_rewrite_rules', 'wpse107528_change_mod_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse107528_change_mod_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $pattern = '/^(?<=RewriteRule\s\^go.+\$1\s)(\[QSA,L\])$/im';
    $replacement = '[L]';
    $rules = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $rules );
    return $rules;
}
```

Beware I haven't tested the Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

```
function wpse107528_add_external_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'go/([0-9]+)/?.*$',
        'wp-content/plugins/xswpc/redirect.php?id=$1',
        'top'
    );
    //Uncomment when testing to avoid already refresh permalink page in wp-admin
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse107528_add_external_rewrite_rule' );
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue, see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L1824).